# html video tag is not able to preload thus not able to autoplay through WebComponents on iOS (Safari or Chrome), but it works on Desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment, web-component

iOS version 14.4

Desired outcome:

1. video autoplays on page load

Video doesn't have an audio track, and I am muting it too.

I am able to get the video tag to work on iOS when I run it directly through static HTML, like

```html
<video id="anshul-video" poster="..." src="..." playsinline="" webkit-playsinline autoplay="" preload="auto" loop="" muted="">
        <source id="something_else" src="..." type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

BUT when I do it through Web Components, it doesn't work. Such as

```js
export default class anshulCommonHeroFeatures extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.setHeroFeatures();
  }

  setHeroFeatures() {
    const commonHeroFeaturesTemplate = document.createElement('template');
    commonHeroFeaturesTemplate.innerHTML = `<video id="..." src="..." playsinline="" autoplay="" preload="auto" loop="" muted="">
        <source id="something_else" src="..." type="video/mp4"
      </video>`;
    this.appendChild(commonHeroFeaturesTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}
window.customElements.define('anshul-common-hero-features', anshulCommonHeroFeatures);
```

The Web Component code works everywhere else. It works on Desktop browsers. It works on Android phone's Chrome. WebComponent page is only failing on iOS.

Any clue or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. To overcome this, I checked for the `video` tags in the DOM of the webcomponent (after the `appendChild`), cloned each `video` node, and replaced the origin `video` tags with clones.

```js
 let videos = this.querySelectorAll('video');
 videos.forEach(vid => {
     vid.parentNode.insertBefore(vid.cloneNode(), vid);
     vid.parentNode.removeChild(vid);
 });
```

This isn't ideal as it could break references to the older nodes, but at least it fixes the autoplay issue.

Comment: Wouldn't using `insertBefore` mean there would be two `<video>` tags after running this code snippet?

Comment: @Mark hi ! yes indeed, thank ! i edited my reply